# Login form cannot get data from back-end in React

Tags: php, reactjs, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-3

in React when I input any value in text field,then Cannot validate user email and password from back-end.

I register users from react, store those users in back-end but my requirement is  when I try to login unregistered user, then show me error user_name and password incorrect.
But in my case just redirect the page cannot check users from back-end.

Please check the code and update the code and also inform me what's the problem in it. Thank you in advance.

user Controller login function in codeIgniter

```
public function login()
  {
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
      header("Access-Control-Request-Headers: GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT");

      $user_email = $this->input->post('user_email');
      $Password   = $this->input->post('Password');

      $row = $this->Usermodel->login_mode($user_email);
      var_dump( $row);
      if (count($row) > 0) {
          //verify password

          if (password_verify($Password, $row['Password'])) {

              $response = array(
                  "status" => 'success',
                  'message' => "User Login successfully"
              );
          } else {

              $response = array(
                  "status" => 'error',
                  'message' => "Password and Username does not match"
              );
          }

      } else {

          $response = array(
              "status" => 'error',
              'message' => 'Account does not exist'
          );

      }

        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($response));
  }
```

user model login function

```
public function login_mode($user_email){
      $query = $this->db->get_where('users',$user_email);
      echo $query->row_array();
  }
```

PostData.js

```
export function PostData(type,userData){
  let headers = new Headers();

  let BaseUrl = 'http://localhost/API/UserController/'
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    fetch(BaseUrl+type ,{
      method:'post',
      'Content_type':'application/json',
      body:JSON.stringify(userData),
      headers
    })
    .then((response)=>{
      response.json()
    })
    .then((responseJson)=>{
      resolve(responseJson)
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      reject(error)
    })
  })
}
```

login.js Reactjs code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link,Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button, Card, CardBody, CardGroup, Col, Container, Form, Input, InputGroup, InputGroupAddon, InputGroupText, Row } from 'reactstrap';
import {PostData} from './PostData';
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user_email:'',
      Password:'',
      redirect :false
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
}

handleSubmit(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  if(this.state.user_email && this.state.Password){
      PostData('login',this.state)
  }
}

handleChange = (event) =>{
  const name  = event.target.name
  const value = event.target.value
  this.setState({ [name]:value })
}
  render() {
    if (this.state.redirect){
      return <Redirect to='/dashboard'/>
    }
    return (
      <div className="app flex-row align-items-center">
        <Container>
          <Row className="justify-content-center">
            <Col md="8">
              <CardGroup>
                <Card className="p-4">
                  <CardBody>
                    <Form  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                      <h1>Login</h1>
                      <p className="text-muted">Sign In to your account</p>
                      <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                        <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                          <InputGroupText>
                            <i className="icon-user"></i>
                          </InputGroupText>
                        </InputGroupAddon>
                        <Input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="user_email" value={this.state.user_email} onChange={this.handleChange} autoComplete="username" required />
                      </InputGroup>
                      <InputGroup className="mb-4">
                        <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                          <InputGroupText>
                            <i className="icon-lock"></i>
                          </InputGroupText>
                        </InputGroupAddon>
                        <Input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="Password" value={this.state.Password} onChange={this.handleChange} autoComplete="current-password" required />
                      </InputGroup>
                      <Row>
                        <Col xs="6">

                          <input  type="submit" color="primary" value="Login" className="px-4" />

                        </Col>
                        <Col xs="6" className="text-right">
                          <Button  color="link"  className="px-0">Forgot password?</Button>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </Form>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
                <Card className="text-white bg-primary py-5 d-md-down-none" style={{ width: '44%' }}>
                  <CardBody className="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <h2>Sign up</h2>
                      <p>welcome here i do many works for you just sign in then start working.</p>
                      <Link to="/register">
                        <Button color="primary" className="mt-3" active tabIndex={-1}>Register Now!</Button>
                      </Link>
                    </div>


        <p>Error:{this.state.error}</p>
                      </CardBody>
                    </Card>
                  </CardGroup>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Container>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Login;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should update this part :

```
fetch("http://localhost/API/UserController/Userlogin",options)
    .then(this.setState({
      user_email : '',
      Password   : '',
      redirect   : true
    }))
```

Instead of redirecting to the dashboard (by setting `redirect` at `true` ) regardless the response from the backend (good or bad), you should create a condition depending on the status code received.

For instance, in case of a response with a 200 status, you indeed redirect to `Dashboard` but if you get another status, you can show an error message to the user for instance

Comment: not work for me please check it again i update whole code also add back-end code in it

Comment: With `fetch`, an error from a request won't necessarily throws an error. You need to check that your fetch was indeed successful like in this example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful)

`fetch("http://localhost/API/UserController/Userlogin",options).then(res => res.json()).then(response => {  if (!response.ok) {/*handle error*/} else {/*redirect*/}})`

Comment: M'y mistake, you need to check `response.ok` before even trying to invoke `response.json() `. Reverse the two `then`s in my previous comment.

Comment: please update your code,what you can say. thank you

Comment: `fetch("http://localhost/API/UserController/Userlogin",options).then(response => { if (!response.ok) { throw New Error('Error') } else {return res}}).then(res => res.json()).catch(err => /* show error message */)` have you tried it ?

Comment: in this case show me same message that show me before....                                                   
JSON 
status success
message User Login successfully
Response payload 
1

{"status":"success","message":"User Login successfully"}

Comment: why code cannot validate the database users?my requirement is when user try to login if not register then say your email and password incorrect when register first then try to login.then he/she will be login,how i try to make this logic i'm so much confused.what i can do next tell me sir?

Comment: You initial problem comes from the usage of `fetch` you had. I suggested you something that should work. From that, you can build your frontend logic. Not sure I'm following where you're still having issue.

Comment: i have simple issue when type wrong email then also redirect the page

Answer (score 0):

First, You need to check the response of the API. Based on that you can navigate the user to the dashboard.

For Example:

If login credentials are correct. Then I will return the response below

```
{
 error: false,
 message: "User has logged in successfully"
 data: {
  .....
 }
}
```

If login credentials are Wrong.

```
{
 error: true,
 data: {}
 message: "Please check the Username and Password"
}
```

You need to modify this part

```
fetch("http://localhost/API/UserController/Userlogin",options)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(response => {
  if (!response.error) {
    this.setState({
      user_email : '',
      Password   : '',
      redirect   : true
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({
        user_email : '',
        Password   : '',
        redirect   : false
      });
  }
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

Comment: not work for me please check it again i update whole code also add back-end code in it

Comment: can you please post the login API response ?

Comment: yeah sure in console show me                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    {user_email: "ss", Password: "ss"}
Login.js:281 Promise {<resolved>: {…}}: Promise[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"[[PromiseValue]]: Objectmessage: "User Login successfully"status: "success": Object
Login.js:272 {user_email: "sulman@gmail.com", Password: "12345"}
Login.js:281 Promise {<resolved>: {…}}

Comment: sir i can update the code and add response also in it please check above

Comment: use my above code. put the console.log(response) send me the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch("http://localhost/API/UserController/Userlogin",options)
.then(this.setState({
  user_email : '',
  Password   : '',
  redirect   : true
}))
.then(res =>console.log(res.json()))
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

The problem is that irrespective of backend response you are setting the redirect true. So when it rerenders it will redirect to another page.
This code redirecting you

```
const state = this.state.redirect;

if(state){
  return <Redirect to="dashboard" />
}
```

Comment: i think you can say right this code only redirecting me so what i ca do first check validation then redirect to dashboard?